# How to redirect page in PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, redirect, header

I have an AJAX function that carry the content of a page (list.php) within a "div" the page (home.php), page (list.php) has a function that checks if the session has expired, if yes, you should go to index.php. It turns out that when I use header ('Location: index.php'); redirection is being done only within the "div" and I wish instead be redirected entire page I am (home.php). This is causing me to stay in home.php and is being shown within "div" the "index.php", and would have is showing only the "index.php"

Comment: @VotetoClose that answer doesn't deal with AJAX requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the redirect in the callback of your AJAX function. You will want to use something like `window.location = ""` in Javascript after there is a response in your AJAX object.

If you are using plain JS, you will want to watch for your `onreadystatechange` event to equal `4`, then do the redirect accordingly depending on the response code and what your intended functionality is.

Comment: So, should I change the Header PHP function by JS, correct?

Comment: The Header function is unnecessary. Implement a javascript redirect in the AJAX callback.